# api.money.stackexchange.com returning questions from 2009?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, date

`http://api.money.stackexchange.com/1.0/questions/?pagesize=1&fromdate=1254960000&todate=1255564793`

```
body => question[0] => [creation_date] => 1254969799
```

1254969799 == Thu, 08 Oct 2009 02:43:19 GMT

I think something's up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, money.stackexchange is the first site seeded with the content of an older, SE 1.0 site.  Accordingly, some of the content is "older" than the site itself, as are some of its [users](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/3/chris-w-rea).

In this case, [BasicallyMoney](http://basicallymoney.com) (now redirects to money.stackexchange).

There's a [meta.money post](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/where-did-all-the-questions-come-from) about it.

Comment: Ah. I don't have access to the beta for that site (I guess I could peek through the API). thanks.